# change attribute of target when click using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, attributes

```
<ul class="todo-list">
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">{{todo.todoContent}}<span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-check" ng-class="{checked:todo.done}" ng-click="todoCheck(todo)" title="check this todo">check</span></li>
  </ul>
```

Now I want change title attribute to "uncheck this todo" and text "check" to "checked" when I click the span element to check target todo. 
Anyone  can help here. Thanks very much.

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjfdfs/6pPD6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    {{todo.todoContent}}
    <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-check" 
    ng-class="{checked:todo.done}" ng-click="todoCheck(todo)" 
    title="{{!todo.done && 'check this todo' || 'uncheck this todo'}}">
        {{!todo.done && 'check' || 'checked'}}
    </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want more fine grained control over the element you clicked, you can do this by using the $event in the ng-click handler.

like

> `ng-click="todoCheck($event, todo)"`

I have used jquery to set the title and content and updated your fiddle.

[Here is the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pPD6/1/)

> `$scope.todoCheck = function ($event, todo) {`
>
> ```
>    var spanElement = $event.srcElement;
>
>    $(spanElement).attr('title', "uncheck this todo");
>
>    $(spanElement).html("checked");
>
>    todo.done = !todo.done;
> ```
>
> `};`

Comment: thanks too. another way to get this done. and yes, I may need to get element directly someday. :)